# Header on alternate left and right side on every page on print

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am creating an HTML page and one of the tasks is to include the company's logo as a header on print.

Now, to display the header on all the pages on print, I am making use of thead, as whatever we include in thead is displayed on all the pages as header like below -

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Logo</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
     <!-- Page content -->
     <tr>
        <td>Main Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, currently the header is appearing on the top-left of each page.

But my requirement is to show header on top-left on the alternate page and on top-right on the rest of the alternate pages.

**Requirement Explained -** So, if we are showing header on top-left on page 1, it should be on top-right on page 2, then on top-left on page 3, top-right on page 4 and so on.

**Using only HTML and CSS**

Now sure how to achieve this scenario. Please provide your insights.

Here's the below code for your reference. Here, when you click on the print button, in the print preview, you will see the header on both pages is on the top-left. But I want it to be on the top-right on the second page

```js
function printPage() {
    try {
        window.print();
    } catch (e) {
        debug("Error caught:", e);
    }


    return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Sanction Letter</title>
  </head>

  <body
    style="
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 16px 0;
      font-family: serif, sans-serif;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: justify;
      width: 90%;
    "
  >
  <input type="button" value="Print with button?" onclick="printPage()"/>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <!-- Content for the header goes here -->
        <tr>
          <td>Header</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea a nesciunt ipsum, numquam consequatur inventore quas fugiat. Placeat nihil natus numquam reprehenderit deserunt aliquam saepe sequi, similique! Voluptas, facilis nisi.
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan done. Added a code snippet